# Other program get lag after running android emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I have a laptop with core i3 processors, 4gb RAM, and Intel HD Graphic VGA. When I tried to launch the emulator it was fine and the other program not lag. But after I run some apps in emulator the other program become lag for example chrome browser lag after some apps opened on emulator. I already tried memu, nox, and mumu emulator but all of that is the same make other program lag. Please anybody who have best solution could help me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different emulators out there. Now there are 3 ways to approach this problem

1. You can try to change the setting in emulators like NOX to make them more efficient.
2. You may be only able to run the emulator and a browser for the specs you are running.
3. You can look at other emulators that i have used on my Macbook Air early 2015 edition. These could range from Bluestacks 4 which is highly well performing emulator even on potato PC's and can be optimized to your liking. Also the KO player is a good idea if you are looking at a more gaming based alternative